# C++ How can i get all line in binary files?

Tags: c++, file, binary

my code in below.

```
int main() {
    Employee* employee = new Employee();
    cout << "Creating File..." << endl;
    fstream file("deneme1.txt",ios::out|ios::binary|ios::ate);
    for(int i=0;i<10;i++){
        if(i<4){
            string name;
            float salary;
            int yearHired;
            cout<<"Enter Name: ";
            cin>>name;
            cout<<"Enter Salary: ";
            cin>>salary;
            cout<<"Enter Year Hired: ";
            cin>>yearHired;
            employee->set_id(i);
            employee->set_name(name);
            employee->set_salary(salary);
            employee->set_yearHired(yearHired);
            file.write((char*)&employee,sizeof(employee));
            file.close();
             }

         }
        file.open("deneme1.txt",ios::in|ios::out|ios::binary);

        file.seekg(0);


        while((file.read((char*)&employee,sizeof(employee)))) {
   cout << employee->get_id();
}



}
```

I have binary file named "deneme1.txt". I record four object to "deneme1.txt". I want to get all line of "deneme1.txt" in `while` loops, but I can only get the last line.(So output is 
"Creating File...
3"
)

How can I get all the line in the file? Maybe the file has only one object?

my class in below

```
class Employee
{
private:
    string name; 
    int id;
    float salary;
    int yearHired;

public:
    void set_name(string n)
    {
        this->name = n;
    }
    void set_id(int i)
    {
        this->id = i;
    }
    string get_name()
    {
        return name;
    }
    int get_id()
    {
        return id;
    }


    void set_salary(float s)
    {
        this->salary = s;
    }

    float get_salary()
    {
        return salary;
    }

    void set_yearHired(int y)
    {
        this->yearHired = y;
    }

    int get_yearHired()
    {
        return yearHired;
    }


};
```

I expect that output be "0 1 2 3"

Comment: Binary files _lines_?? How do you define a _line_ in a binary file? Care to explain please.

Comment: Show your header for your class. if `name` is a std::string you can't do this.

Comment: ***My have binary file named "deneme1.txt"*** normally binary files do not have a  `.txt` extension.

Comment: What is `Employee`?  If it is non-POD, this code invokes undefined behavior.

Comment: Now that you show Employee. You can't do what you want. Employee is not a POD.

Comment: What I mean is since Employee is not a POD you can't do `file.write((char*)&employee,sizeof(employee));` or `file.read((char*)&employee,sizeof(employee))` both of these invoke Undefined Behavior.

Comment: If I could i get last object's id, why can't i get all object's id?

Comment: @BatuhanÖzkan -- None of this code will work, so asking "why I can't do x with the id's" is invalid.  If you want proof, what is `sizeof(Employee)` equal to?  It will be the same, regardless of the `size()` that `name` gives you.  So how is this supposed to work if `name` was 1,000 characters?

Comment: So How can  i fix this problem? In summary, i want to write from class to binary file, and i want get records by using id.

Comment: The simplest way is to not use a binary file. A second way is to make Employee a POD (change name to a cstring of a fixed size and make sure you obey its size limitation). Also you need to fix the logical mistakes in your code.

Comment: @BatuhanÖzkan [Look here at sizeof(Employee)](https://www.ideone.com/s8FehW).  It is 48 even if `name` has 100 characters.

Comment: *So How can i fix this problem?* -- What is the layout of your file?  In other words, how would another application be able to read your file and recreate Employees from the file?  That is the first step you should be figuring out -- it has nothing to do with coding.  Once you know this, then it doesn't matter if it is a binary file, text file, etc.  This in a nutshell is *object serialization* -- google for it.

Answer (score -1):

After some cleanup, this should not have any undefined behavior.

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

class Employee {
private:
    std::string name;
    int id;
    float salary;
    int yearHired;
public:
    Employee(const std::string &name, int id, float salary, int yearHired) : name(name), id(id), salary(salary),
                                                                             yearHired(yearHired) {}
    Employee(Employee const&) = delete;
    Employee& operator=(Employee const&) = delete;
    int get_id() const {
        return id;
    }
};

int main() {
    std::cout << "Creating File..." << std::endl;
    {
        std::ofstream file("deneme1.txt", std::ios::out | std::ios::binary | std::ios::ate);
        std::string name;
        for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
                float salary;
                int yearHired;
                std::cout << "Enter Name: ";
                std::cin >> name;
                std::cout << "Enter Salary: ";
                std::cin >> salary;
                std::cout << "Enter Year Hired: ";
                std::cin >> yearHired;
                Employee employee(name, i, salary, yearHired);
                file.write((char *) &employee, sizeof(employee));
        }
    }  // file.close();

    std::ifstream file("deneme1.txt", std::ios::in | std::ios::binary);

    char* employeeData = new char[sizeof(Employee)];
    {
        const Employee &employee = *reinterpret_cast<const Employee *>(employeeData);
        while ((file.read((char *) &employee, sizeof(employee)))) {
            std::cout << employee.get_id();
        }
    }
    delete[]employeeData;

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Comment: But the output is `0123` instead of `0 1 2 3`.

Comment: You can't `fwrite` a `struct` containing a `string` like that. You will need to serialize the data and not the string object.

Comment: @BoR -- Did you not see my comment on why this could never work?  `sizeof(Employee)` when run on ideone is 48, regardless of how many characters are in `name`.  So this solution is no solution.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie Yes, is saw it. But as long as you don't touch the std::string member, this "works". As it stands it will work for POD data types. But, true, if you really want a binary format it needs to be defined and I didn't take to time to do that.

Comment: @RetiredNinja Correct, that's why I don't touch that member and another reason why I have to allocate the data area as a char array to avoid running its constructor and destructor. `reinterpret_cast` should be a hint that something is tricky here.

Comment: So this is an example of what to never do. I don't see how it answers the question.